# Can't have spaces in variable in Bash script when posting to sendgrid API

Tags: json, bash, sendgrid

I am trying to make a script for Nagios to send mail using the Sendgrid API.

When I don't have any spaces in my body/subject it works just fine. But when I do have it I get this error:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   144  100    63  100    81    140    181 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   181
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 6
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}
```

This is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
sendgridapikey="................................................."
mailto="mymail@mail.com"
mailfrom="sendermail@mail.com"
subject="subject here"
body="DefaultNagiosMailBody\n\nTest"
while getopts a:t:f:s:b: option
do
case "${option}"
in
a) sendgridapikey=${OPTARG};;
t) mailto=${OPTARG};;
f) mailfrom=${OPTARG};;
s) subject=${OPTARG};;
b) body=${OPTARG};;
esac
done
curl -X POST "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send" -H "Authorization: Bearer $sendgridapikey" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \
'{"personalizations":[{"to":[{"email":"'$mailto'"}],"subject":"'$subject'"}],"from":{"email":"'$mailfrom'","name": "Nagios"},"content":[{"type":"text/plain","value":"'$body'"}]}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not quote the variables properly. Write like this:

```
'{"personalizations":[{"to":[{"email":"'"$mailto"'"}],"subject":"'"$subject"'"}],"from":{"email":"'"$mailfrom"'","name": "Nagios"},"content":[{"type":"text/plain","value":"'"$body"'"}]}'
```

Notice that I wrapped all variables within double-quotes.
The way you wrote it,
they were not wrapped within quotes at all.

To show in a simplified example, your code looked essentially like this:

```
curl -d 'quoted string '$var' and some more'
```

It may seem like `$var` is quoted, but it's not.
The single-quote on its left closes the single-quoted text that started before `quoted`. The single-quote on its right starts a new single-quoted text, ending with `more`. `$var` itself is not quoted here.
This is how it would be quoted:

```
curl -d 'quoted string '"$var"' and some more'
```

I applied the same logic in the suggestion at the top.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution Janos.